# Ignore objects over hover

Tags: html, css

I have a background-image with transform scale and rotate. So whenever you have your cursor over it it will rotate 15deg and scale 2.

I want to place my logo over it but how can I do it so whenever I have my cursor over the logo it will still counts as I am hovering at the background? **CSS:**

```
.background-image:hover {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -999;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("whatever.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  -moz-filter: blur(8px);
  -o-filter: blur(8px);
  -ms-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);

  transform: rotate(12deg) scale(2);
  -o-transform: rotate(12deg) scale(2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(12deg) scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg) scale(2);

  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Here I have a div over the background, if I hold my cursor over the div the hover for the background doesn't count anymore and it goes back. How can I make the div still visible and when I hover my mouse over the div the background will go back? CSS for the div:

```
<div class="logo-position"></div>

.logo-position {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: white;
  top: 80px;
}
```

The "hitbox" for the div is also very weird. I can take the cursor to the right of the div and it still counts as I have my cursor inside the div as the background transform goes back. Anybody see anything I have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.logo-position` class.  This should cause the logo to ignore the hover event and let it pass through.  Note that it will ignore *all* events, so it won't be clickable either.

Comment: This worked thanks, I just had to remove the margins and added a float: left and it worked I'll just position it with a parent div instead

Answer (score 1):

If the `.logo-position` div is a child of the `.background-image` div it will allow the hover to apply to the logo.

Comment: The problem with that is that the logo will get blurred and transformed as well but I don't want that to happen

Comment: Ah, yes it would. -_-